# M2: How to redirect contact form page to CMS page

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect, contact-form, 301-redirect

I tried to 301 redirect contact form page URL to custom cms page URL with Magento 2's rewrites, but it does not seem to redirect the URL for some reason.

Is there some special trick to be done with contact form redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom url rewrite in your admin.

**Target path**: custom-cms-url (without any slahes /)

**Request path**: contact

Make sure you have a cron job setup for reindexing and that the url rewrite was made for the correct store view.

Comment: Well I think this worked after all. I tried this in live and it does not work, but in testing installation it does work so I guess it has to be a caching issue or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.htacess write following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

or you can do with admin panel also

`1st -> go to admin -> marketing -> seo&search -> urlrewrite` change url according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overwriting contact form. To do that create a `contact_index_index.xml` file in `Your_Theme_Folder > Magento_Contact > layout`

You can here add CMS block for example.

You can also overwrite template by creating a `form.phtml` file in `Your_Theme_Folder > Magento_Contact > templates` to edit the default form template.

With those two methods, you can fully overwrite the default contact page.

If you really want to use a CMS Page I think the best way is to disable `contact us` feature in `Configuration > Contacts > Contacts us` and disable contact us. Then create your CMS Page with the default contact url.